# Тбилиси - тбилисский, Аксу - аксусский?

Tags: словообразование

Как правильно писать прилагательное от слова "Аксу"? Аксуский или аксусский?

Comment: Ялта - ялтинский, Аксу - аксинский

Comment: Ялт/а – ялт/инск/ий – это совсем другая орфограмма, а именно выбор ЕНСК/ИНСК, а не  удвоение СС при  использовании суффикса  СК. Скорее всего, вы знаете это правило, но просто неосторожно поспешили с выводом.
Розенталь, п.14 и п. 15  http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=44#pp44

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правка текста была не очень удачной, сначала было так: ***Тбилиси – тбилисский, Одесса – одесский. Аксу – аксусский?***

Из Википедии: ***Аксуский*** район: Аксуский район (Алматинская область). Аксуский район (Павлодарская область).

Сложная тема, **много факторов** надо учитывать, иногда без словаря и не обойдешься.

При выборе суффиксов для прилагательных, образованных от географических названий, в том числе иноязычных, существуют **две тенденции**. С одной стороны, слово должно вписываться в фонетическую систему языка, с другой стороны – требуется обеспечить минимальное искажение исходного названия (особенно для малоизвестных или иноязычных топонимов).

Розенталь уделяет вопросу много внимания http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=44#pp44   Можно ориентировать на такую информацию:

**Примечание.** В словах ***бордоский, тартуский*** и т. п. пишется одна буква с, так как производящая основа не оканчивается на -с (Бордо, Тарту).

**Пояснение**

*Ялта – **ялт/инск/ий**,* суффикс ИНСК, а не СК.

*Одесс/а – **одес/ск/ий**, Тбилиси – **тбилис/ск/ий***, суффикс СК частично накладывается на основу.

*Аксу – **аксу/ск/ий***, нет наложения СК на основу, ударное окончание.